# How can I sort in increasing order?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

```
sample = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {1000, 10, 10}];
trp = Map[Transpose, sample];
GOEe = sample + trp;
eigs = Flatten[Map[Eigenvalues, GOEe]];
distpars = 
  FindDistributionParameters[Eigens, NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]];

Show[Histogram[eigs, Automatic, "PDF"], 
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma] /. distpars, x], {x, -20, 20}]]


 
(*Sorted Eigs*) 
sortedEigs = eigs[ordering[eigs]];
```

Hello, this is my code to sort eigs in increasing order. However, I keep getting message errors.
Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: try `sortedEigs = eigs[[Ordering[eigs]]]`?

Comment: Or just use `sortedEigs = Sort[eigs]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, I get "Nonatomic expression sorted at position 1 in Sort[eigs]" error message.

Comment: @kglr I get I get "Nonatomic expression sorted at position 1 in "Ordering[eigs]" error message

Comment: Start by clearing any old definitions using `Clear["Global\`*"]`  and in `FindDistributionParameters` the first argument should presumably be `eigs` since `Eigens` is undefined.

Comment: Did you verify if `eigs` is a list before trying out kglr's or Bob's suggestions?

Comment: @J.M. Yes eigs is a list

Comment: Show us `First[eigs]`?